# Recursion in Scheme with Booleans

Tags: recursion, scheme, boolean

How would you write a base case for a recursive function that is also a boolean? The problem comes up in the project Scoring Poker Hands in *Simply Scheme* (http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch15/poker.html).

The only thing I can think of is putting `#t` when the list has reached the count of 1 or less, but then the function only returns `#t` because all lists would be reduced to one element in it.

Comment: You need to edit in some code so that we understand what you mean by `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it depends on what the function is supposed to do.  For instance, an `every?` function that check whether every element of a list satisfies some predicate should return `#t` in the base case, because it *is* true that every element in an empty list satisfies the predicate.  On the other hand, a `some?` function should return `#f`, since it is *false* that some element in an empty list satisfies the predicate.

```
(define (some? predicate list)
  (if (null? list)
      #f
      (if (predicate (car list))
          #t
          (some? predicate (cdr list)))))
```

Of course, with functions returning a boolean like this, you can often encode the logic more directly by using `and`, `or`, and `not`:

```
(define (some? predicate list)
  (and (not (null? list))
       (or (predicate (car list))
           (some? predicate (cdr list)))))
```

The `every?` case would be:

```
(define (every? predicate list)
  (if (null? list)
      #t
      (if (not (predicate (car list)))
          #f
          (every? predicate (cdr list)))))
```

and the more direct version of `every?` (using boolean operators rather than `if`, `#t`, and `#f`):

```
(define (every? predicate list)
  (or (null? list)
      (and (predicate (car list))
           (every? predicate (cdr list)))))
```